# Heroku Rails: String gets auto-converted to Decimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 3.2 app on Heroku cedar stack.

I have a very simple model:

```
# string value_type
# decimal value
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :value_type

  validates :value_type, presence: true,
                         inclusion: %( ab bc cde )
  validates :value, presence: true,
                    numericality: true
end
```

When I create a new object and try to save it locally, running on SQLite, it works without problems.

When I try to create a new object on Heroku, it treats value_type as BigDecimal, no matter what I assign to it.

Anyone have any ideas on how to debug this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Check your database, what is the data-type of the value_type

Comment: Checked my migrations and schema.db, those show it as string.  How would I check it against the actual DB?

Comment: heroku pg:psql just gives me a timeout

Comment: a side note: are you sure you really need `attr_accessible :value, :value_type`? If these are DB columns AR already provides corresponding getter and setter methods. It is possible your accessors override the original AR ones, or conflict somehow.

Comment: @khustochka yes, I do, cause there are other fields that I don't want to be accessible, such as a parent association

Comment: sorry my comment was irrelevant. I mixed attr_accessible with attr_accessor